# Response custom error when key not satisfies the exact value in couchbase view

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I have a document like -

```
{
 "fullUserName": "xxyz",
 "userFirstName": "xx",
 "userLastName": "xx",
 "primaryRole": "xy",
 "actualRole": "rrr",
 "userId": "abcd1234",
 "password":"c28f5c7cb675d41c7763ab0c42d",
 "type":"login",
 "channels":"*"
}
```

and view -

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if(doc.userId,doc.password,doc.type){
      emit([doc.userId,doc.password,doc.type],doc);
    }
}
```

When the key matches with the docment's property it return the document otherwise it return empty JSON like -

```
{"total_rows":2,"rows":[
  ]
}
```

Now I want to response the error message in JSON format when the key does not match for example-

```
{
  "Error-Code":"400",
  "Error-Msg":"user id and password does not match"
}
```

Is there any way to do so,Please correct if I am moving in the wrong direction.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't directly expose the view query result to your users but interpret it instead.

So make a view request, look at the response and do the business logic of checking there. For example:

> "if result is empty it can only be because the user is unknown or the password hash didn't match the user, so return a business-specific error message, otherwise carry on with login"

There's no way you can change the behavior and response format of the server, and that doesn't make much sense to do so anyway. This is the API and contract of how you interact with the server. You should add your own business logic in a layer in between.